How to darken my new wood furniture
I bought two tables online and it turned out one of them is a much darker shade of wood than the other. If possible, I’ll like to darken it a few shades to match the other pieces in my room a bit more
Here’s a pic of the two pieces

It’s new furniture, so I don’t want to sand it down. I’m new to all this so maybe it’s not possible, but I’m looking for a simple stain or technique which I can apply to make the whole thing darker.
Any tips?

If you don't mind making the grain of the wood less visible, a glaze (a tinted varnish) could be applied. The problem is that these are available in both oil-based and wood-based formulations, and you would need to use one comparable with the existing finish (requires some testing with solvents)...
... Unless you first apply a layer of shellac, which is compatible with both.
In fact, shellac adds some color of its own. I have successfully used multiple layers of shellac to slowly build up color, sealing it with a top coat of varnish when it got into the right range.
Fir more details on handing these materials and processes, I recommend asking on the Woodworking stack. Details of wood finish and modifying same are a better fit there than they are here.

"Fir more details"... whether intentional or a typo... that's funny. ;)
